# pandas color cell based on value of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I would like to color in red cells of a DataFrame on one column, based on the value of another column.

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  { 'color_A_in_red': True , 'A': 1 },
  { 'color_A_in_red': False , 'A': 2 },
  { 'color_A_in_red': True , 'A': 2 },
])
```

should give:
[image: colored_df]

I know how to color a cell of a df in red but only based on the value of this cell, not the value of another cell:

```
df_style = df.style
df_style.applymap(func=lambda x: 'background-color: red' if x == 2 else None, subset=['A'])
df_style
```

[image: wring_color_df]

Is there a way to color cells of a DataFrame based on the value of another column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use custom function for DataFrame of styles is most flexible solution here:

```
def highlight(x):
    c = f"background-color:red" 
    #condition
    m = x["color_A_in_red"]
    # DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    # set columns by condition
    df1.loc[m, 'A'] = c
    return df1


df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

Comment: How to remove ```color_A_in_red``` column after adding ```style``` attribute when exporting to excel for example. For me it gives error message.

Comment: @Michael - do you need [hide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) ?

Comment: I have used ```hide``` option but it doesn't work for me for some reason.