# How to apply conditional color stying to a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a styler function to a df but getting this error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
ValueError: Function <function highlight at 0x0000029D89935F30> resulted in the apply method collapsing to a Series.
Usually, this is the result of the function returning a single value, instead of list-like.
```

I have a dataframe like below

```
Value       Limit    Actual
Issues      < 33     0
Rating      > 4      4.2
Complaints  < 15     18
Time        30 - 45  41
Tip         --       -
```

I want to color the column `Actual` based on the `Limit` column.

- For example if the `Limit` has "< 33", I want to color `Actual` as Green if the value in `Actual` column is less than 30, if not Red. Similarly for other rows as well.
- If the `Limit` has "30-45", I want to color `Actual` as Green if the value in `Actual` column is between 30 & 45 , if not Red.
- If the `Limit` has "-", I want to color `Actual` as Yellow.

Based on this SO question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71496253/pandas-color-cell-based-on-value-of-other-column), I created a function that evaluates the logic.

```
import re

def highlight(row):
    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', row['Limit'])
    if row['Value'] in ('Issues','Rating','Complaints'):
        if '>' in row['Limit'] and row['Actual'] > numbers[0]:
            color = 'green'
        elif row['Actual'] < numbers[0]:
            color = 'green'
        else:
            color = 'red'
    else:
        if len(numbers) == 0:
            color = 'yellow'
        elif row['Actual'] > numbers[0] and row['Actual'] < numbers[1]:
            color = 'green'
        else:
            color = 'red'
    return f"background-color: {color}"
```

However, when I try `df.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)`, I get the error message at the beginning of the question.

How do I properly implement my logic to get the coloring I want?
Below is what I want when I export this df to excel.

[image: screenshot of table with coloring]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message identifies the problem: "Usually, this is the result of the function returning a single value, instead of list-like." You have multiple columns, but you're only returning the style for one, and `df.style.apply()` doesn't know which one. [The docs explain](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

> `func` should take a Series if `axis` in [0,1] and return a list-like object of same length, or a Series, not necessarily of same length, with valid index labels considering `subset`.
>
> ...
>
> The elements of the output of `func` should be CSS styles as strings, in the format 'attribute: value; attribute2: value2; ...' or, if nothing is to be applied to that element, an empty string or `None`.

So in this case, you could simply return a list with no styles specified for the plain columns:

```
return [None, None, f"background-color: {color}"]
```

Or you could return a Series with just the "Actual" column style specified. This would still work even if you rearranged the columns or added more.

```
return pd.Series({'Actual': f"background-color: {color}"})
```

(Sidenote: I'm surprised it doesn't allow a dict, i.e. `return {'Actual': f"background-color: {color}"}`.)