# How to apply conditional color styling to a column in a Multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I already had a question answered for conditionally applying color with a normal Dataframe. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468691/how-to-apply-conditional-color-stying-to-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

The question I have is how do I do that with a multi-index data-frame? The dataframe in the previous question was

```
Value       Limit    Actual
Issues      < 33     0
Rating      > 4      4.2
Complaints  < 15     18
Time        30 - 45  41
Tip         --       -
```

The new dataframe is the same dataframe but with header like below

```
df.columns =pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['summary'], df.columns])
df
```

So the new dataframe is like so

```
Summary
Value       Limit    Actual
Issues      < 33     0
Rating      > 4      4.2
Complaints  < 15     18
Time        30 - 45  41
Tip         --       -
```

The out put expected is like the previous question itself but with a additional header row at the top.

[image]

I tried replacing `row['Limit']` with `x.loc[:,idx[:,'Limit']]` where `idx` is `pd.IndexSlice` but it did not work

```
import re

def highlight(row):
    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', row['Limit'])
    if row['Value'] in ('Issues','Rating','Complaints'):
        if '>' in row['Limit'] and row['Actual'] > numbers[0]:
            color = 'green'
        elif row['Actual'] < numbers[0]:
            color = 'green'
        else:
            color = 'red'
    else:
        if len(numbers) == 0:
            color = 'yellow'
        elif row['Actual'] > numbers[0] and row['Actual'] < numbers[1]:
            color = 'green'
        else:
            color = 'red'
    return f"background-color: {color}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change:

```
row['Limit']
```

to:

```
row[('summary', 'Limit')]
```

for select by MultiIndex in columns.

EDIT:

If use:

```
row[(slice(None),'Limit')]
row[idx[:,'Actual']]
```

output is one element `Series`.

So need select first value in this methods for scalar:

```
row[(slice(None),'Limit')].iat[0]
row[idx[:,'Actual']].iat[0]
```

Comment: The text `Summary` is dynamic & can change based on a variable. Is there another way (by getting the column name of the first row of the header)?

Comment: @moys - I think simpliest is use `row[('summary', 'Limit')]` , is not possible create `summary` form variable?

Comment: I will do that itself. It is easier to read also. One last follow up. How do I change the background color of "Summary"? Only the header, not any columns. I know this is different question but thought the answer may be short as well. If I put something like `df.style.set_properties(subset=[('Summary')],**{'background-color': 'red'})`, the whole df color is changing, I just want the header to change. I will put a new question if that is better.

Comment: @moys - I found [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Table-Styles) - part [11], [12]